# NDSolve to solve a PDF

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve numerically the following PDE:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p(x,t)=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}p(x,t)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}[x^2\,p(x,t)],\;x\ge0,\;t\ge0,
$$
where $p(x,t)$ denotes a probability density function. The PDF is subject to the following conditions:

1. $p(x,0+)=\delta(x-x_0)$, where $x_0\ge0$ is a given constant and $\delta(x)$ denotes the Delta function;
2. $\int_{0}^\infty p(x,t)\,dx=1$ for all $t\ge0$;
3. Two limit-type boundary conditions:
   $$
   \lim_{x\to0+}\left\{p(x,t)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[x^2\,p(x,t)]\right\}=0,
   $$
   and
   $$
   \lim_{x\to+\infty}\left\{p(x,t)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[x^2\,p(x,t)]\right\}=0.
   $$

I am a novice in Mathematica, but having searched stackexchange.com for similar questions, I was able to come up with the following code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
$Assumptions = x >= 0 && Subscript[x, 0] >= 0 && t >= 0;

tmax = 15;
xmax = 15;
Subscript[x, 0] = 2;
sol = NDSolve[{D[p[x, t], {t, 1}] == -D[p[x, t], {x, 1}] + 
      1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 2}],
        p[x, 0] == D[HeavisideTheta[x - Subscript[x, 0]], {x, 1}],
        ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> xmax) == 0,
    ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> 0) == 0},
   p, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, xmax}];

pxt = First[p /. sol];

Plot3D[pxt[x, t], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All]
```

It basically yields the trivial solution $p(x,t)\equiv 0$, which is because the normalization constraint 2 is not taken into account.

My question is whether it's possible to feed a constraint of this type of NDSolve?

**UPDATE** This equation can be solved analytically. Its exact solution (evaluated using Mathematica) is illustrated in the following figure:
[image]

I would like to compare the exact solution and the numerical solution. What I need help with is getting the latter using Mathematica.

Comment: Let's ignore condition 2 for a moment. Since you specify one boundary condition for $t$ and two for $x$, isn't the solution fully determined...? Is there any other solution?

Comment: In this case the normalization constraint is important, for the problem is singular at the end points for $x$.

Comment: So what solution are you expecting?

Comment: It's actually a well-known equation and its closed-form analytic solution is also known. The solution involves a $[0,\infty)$-integral of the product of two Whittaker W-functions (integration is with respect to the first index of the W-functions).

Comment: Calculate that analytic solution for these parameters with Mathematica and compare. As I said, the system is fully determined without constraint 2, so including it makes the system overdetermined. Btw, you should immediately replace `Subscript[x,0]` with `x0`, because `Subscript` is not atomic in Mathematica, so NDSolve will "see" the `x` inside it and treat it like the independent variable of `p`.

Comment: That's actually what I would like to do: to compare the exact solution and the numerical solution. The problem though is that I don't know how to get the latter. RE: Subscript - I actually do have $x_0$ in my script; it's just that for some reason it got copied to SE as `Subscript[x,0]`. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer I've added a picture showing the exact solution (evaluated numerically using Mathematica).

Comment: Could you also post the code you used to make that plot?

Answer (score 4):

This is a long comment that answers the question, What is the problem?  I don't have an answer to the question, What is the fix?, at this point.

The problem is, I believe, condition 1.  I'm afraid my background in PDEs is weak, but numerically, using the method of lines (the default in this case), condition 1 is not integrated.  Basically, the initial value for `p[x, 0]` is set equal to the value of `D[HeavisideTheta[x - x0], {x, 1}]`, which is the value of `DiracDelta[x - 2]`, at each point on the spatial grid.  The value is used as an initial condition to begin integration along the line.  The value is either `0` or undefined.  Depending on `xmax`, the spatial grid is unlikely to include the point `x == 2.`, so the integrator sees initial conditions of all zeros.  Given those initial conditions, one should expect to get the trivial solution.

Here is a way to test it: Find a value of `xmax` such that the spatial grid lands on `x == 2.`  The default grid size in this case is 49 points or 48 intervals.  So choosing `xmax` to be a divisor of 48 that is at least two ends up evaluating `DiracDelta[x - 2]` at `x == 2.`.

```
tmax = 15;
xmax = 3;
x0 = 2;
dh[x_?NumericQ] := (Sow[x]; DiracDelta[x - x0]);
{sol, {grid}} = Reap@NDSolve[{
     D[p[x, t], {t, 1}] == -D[p[x, t], {x, 1}] + 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 2}], 
     p[x, 0] == dh[x],
     ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> xmax) == 0,
     ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> 0) == 0}, 
    p, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, xmax}];
```

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`. >>
>   NDSolve::ndnum: ....

```
grid
(*
  {0., 0.0625, 0.125, 0.1875, 0.25, 0.3125, 0.375, 0.4375, 0.5, 0.5625, \
   0.625, 0.6875, 0.75, 0.8125, 0.875, 0.9375, 1., 1.0625, 1.125, \
   1.1875, 1.25, 1.3125, 1.375, 1.4375, 1.5, 1.5625, 1.625, 1.6875, \
   1.75, 1.8125, 1.875, 1.9375, 2., 2.0625, 2.125, 2.1875, 2.25, 2.3125, \
   2.375, 2.4375, 2.5, 2.5625, 2.625, 2.6875, 2.75, 2.8125, 2.875, \
   2.9375, 3.}
*)
```

Or one can set the spatial grid for `xmax = 15` to contain `2.`:

```
Reap@NDSolve[{
   D[p[x, t], {t, 1}] == -D[p[x, t], {x, 1}] + 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 2}], 
   p[x, 0] == D[HeavisideTheta[x - x0], {x, 1}],
   ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> xmax) == 0,
   ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> 0) == 0}, 
  p, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, xmax},
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MinPoints" -> 4*15 + 1, "MaxPoints" -> 4*15 + 1, 
      "DifferenceOrder" -> Automatic}}]
```

> NDSolve::ndinpd: The initial conditions did not evaluate to an array of numbers of depth 1 on the spatial grid. Initial conditions for partial differential equations should be specified as scalar functions of the spatial variables. >>
>   ....

---

**Update: Possible workaround**

One might approximate the delta function by any of the standard formulas.  For instance a unit-area box:

```
Block[{tmax = 15,
  xmax = 15,
  x0 = 2,
  width = 1*^-2},
 sol = NDSolve[{
    D[p[x, t], {t, 1}] == -D[p[x, t], {x, 1}] + 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 2}], 
    p[x, 0] == width UnitBox[(x - x0) / width],
    ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> xmax) == 0,
    ((p[x, t] - 1/2*D[x^2*p[x, t], {x, 1}]) /. x -> 0) == 0}, 
   p, {t, 0, tmax}, {x, 0, xmax},
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
       "MinPoints" -> Round[xmax/width], 
       "MaxPoints" -> 1 + Round[10 xmax/width],
       "DifferenceOrder" -> Automatic}}]; pxt = First[p /. sol];
 Plot3D[pxt[x, t], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax}, 
  PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
 ]
```

> NDSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 15001 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x. >>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: One can also use the initial condition `p[x, 0] == PDF[NormalDistribution[0, width], x - x0]`.  At first, it would finish running.  But restarting the kernel fixed that.

Comment: Many thanks. Let me play with this now to see how this solution compares to the exact solution.

Comment: @Alex You're welcome.  I just realized I left a "not" out of my comment -- at first, the `NDSolve` would **not** finish with a normal approximation to delta.  That seemed to be one-time glitch.

Comment: I actually didn't pay attention to that. What do you mean by "it wouldn't finish running"?

Comment: @Alex I mean `NDSolve` ran for tens of minutes and accumulated several gigabytes of data in memory.  Then I killed kernel.  But it's irrelevant, since when I tried again in a fresh kernel, it finished after a little while (a minute or less maybe).  Probably a memory leak or bug -- I've seen it happen before after a long session.  It could be a definition from earlier work I was doing lurking in the kernel that interfered with it.  *Mathematica* is not completely bug-free, so that's a possibility at least.

Comment: "Numerically, using the method of lines (the default in this case), condition 1 is not integrated." Yeah, actually this has been (vaguely) mentioned in the **possible issue** of [`DiracDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html):  _Numerical routines will typically miss the contributions from measures at single points._